# Extract data from xml string

Tags: c#, xml

Let's say I have an xml string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Return version="1.0">
<File>1</File>
<URL>2</URL>
<SourceUUID>1191CF90-5A32-4D29-9F90-24B2EXXXXXX0</SourceUUID>
</Return>
```

and I want to extract the value of `SourceUUID`, how?

I tried:

```
           XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

            foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("SourceUUID"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
```

Comment: is this line gives error : XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(readStream.ReadToEnd());

Comment: @PranayRana that's the xml string i edited, see now

Comment: Your code does not produce this error.

Comment: Forget about the error, I only want to extract the data, how please?

Comment: You are extracting the data. It writes the `SourceUUID` element to the console. What do you actually want?

Comment: Use this: Console.WriteLine(element.Value);

Comment: I need only the content inside the elemet, is it possible?

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question to remove mentions of this elusive error, and instead make it clearer that you want to extract the **value** of the specified element.

Comment: @MattJones I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is the content of the `SourceUUID` element, and there's only going to be 1 in the XML, you can do this:

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        var value = doc.Descendants("SourceUUID").SingleOrDefault()?.Value;
```

If there are going to be more than one, you can do this:

```
        var values = doc.Descendants("SourceUUID").Select(x => x.Value);
```

This gives you an enumerable of strings that are the text values of the elements.

Comment: @tgg I really encourage you to read more about LINQ to XML - it's an extremely useful way of consuming XML data.